# how to write PHP Unit test for an entity using hooks

Tags: testing

I am to write a unit test for a simple extension using hooks with postprocess and formbuild. How can I do it? Please provide some example.

Comment: This documentation does not explain how to use hooks only showing this: public function hook_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
    // listen to hook_civicrm_post
  }

Answer (score 1):

An example is in `tests/phpunit/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/PDFLetterCommonTest.php`, testing that `hook_civicrm_tokenValues` works correctly on PDF letters.

You write a [function using the hook](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/PDFLetterCommonTest.php#L136-L140), but you can name it whatever you want.  Then you call [$this->hookClass->setHook](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/PDFLetterCommonTest.php#L100), specifying the function name.